# How can we provide default Back key press behaviour to a custom button tap event in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an Windows Phone 8 application. In a page i have placed one Button and one textbox. When user Taps on textbox, the default keyboard comes up. Now, keyboard is on display mode and i clicked on button which navigates me to another screen. After navigation it is giving me half the screen size to be in black and that is actually keyboard. So can anyone tell me how to hide the keyboard first and then navigate to another screen?

Is it possible to assign override OnBackKeyPress method to the button control? If not, what is the other way to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is changing the focus from textbox to page. Just add this code to button's tap event:

```
this.Focus();
```